# SQL Server 2017 Instance Installation Failure

Tags: sql-server, uninstallation, sql-server-2017

HELP GET RID OF SQL SERVER 2017 INSTANCE !!!

When I attempted to install an instance of SQL Server 2017, the install failed.  Then I attempt to uninstall and the reinstall.  This failed as well.  The reason the uninstalled seemed to fail appeared to be that when I uninstalled from Programs and Features, at the of the uninstall process, a prompt read "ScenarioEngine.exe stopped working."  I have attempted to repair the ScenarioEngine.exe by repairing .net 4.6 with a fixer download (suggested here), but it's not worked.  Before re-installing, I also remove registry entries mentioned for \Microsoft SQL Server\ and I manually remove Program Files directories x64 & x86.  I makes sure cache is cleared with WSReset and browser histories and datafiles cleared.  I've tried everything mentioned and cannot get rid of SQL SERVER 2017 Instance to reinstall a good instance.  There appears to be no remaining crumb of sql server 2017 local db, but clearly there is one ... I also have re-booted after each clean - prior to an attempt to remove.

> Overall summary:
>       Final result:                  Failed: see details below
>       Exit code (Decimal):           -2068578302
>       Start time:                    2018-01-23 16:51:14
>       End time:                      2018-01-23 16:53:13
>       Requested action:              Repair
>
> Setup completed with required actions for features.
>     Troubleshooting information for those features:
>       Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
>
> Machine Properties:
>       Machine name:                  IRCA-N679MXW1
>       Machine processor count:       8
>       OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise (10.0.14393)
>       OS service pack:
>       OS region:                     United States
>       OS language:                   English (United States)
>       OS architecture:               x64
>       Process architecture:          64 Bit
>       OS clustered:                  No
>
> Product features discovered:
>       Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
>       SQL Server 2017      WENDISQL2017         MSSQL14.WENDISQL2017           Database Engine Services                 1033                 Standard Edition     14.0.1000.169   No         Yes
>       SQL Server 2017                                                          Client Tools Connectivity                1033                                      14.0.1000.169   No         Yes
>       SQL Server 2017                                                          Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033                                      14.0.1000.169   No         Yes
>       SQL Server 2017                                                          Client Tools SDK                         1033                                      14.0.1000.169   No         Yes
>
> Package properties:
>       Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2017 
>       ProductName:                   SQL Server 2017
>       Type:                          RTM
>       Version:                       14
>       SPLevel:                       0
>       Installation location:         C:\Users\Wendi_Turner\Work Folders\Desktop\SQL2017\x64\setup\
>       Installation edition:          Standard
>
> User Input Settings:
>       ACTION:                        Repair
>       AGTDOMAINGROUP:                
>       AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 
>       AGTSVCPASSWORD:                
>       AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
>       ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
>       ASSVCACCOUNT:                  
>       ASSVCPASSWORD:                 
>       ASTELSVCACCT:                  
>       ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              
>       ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
>       CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
>       CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 
>       CLTSVCPASSWORD:                
>       CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180123_165114\ConfigurationFile.ini
>       CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
>       CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                
>       CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               
>       ENU:                           true
>       EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 
>       EXTSVCPASSWORD:                
>       FAILOVERCLUSTERGROUP:          
>       FAILOVERCLUSTERNETWORKNAME:    
>       FTSVCACCOUNT:                  
>       FTSVCPASSWORD:                 
>       HELP:                          false
>       IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     false
>       IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
>       INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
>       INSTANCENAME:                  WENDISQL2017
>       ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
>       ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           
>       ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391
>       ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          
>       ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
>       ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         
>       ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
>       ISSVCPASSWORD:                 
>       ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
>       ISTELSVCACCT:                  
>       ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              
>       ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
>       ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
>       ISWORKERSVCCERT:               
>       ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             
>       ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           
>       ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
>       MRCACHEDIRECTORY:
>       QUIET:                         false
>       QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
>       SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$WENDISQL2017
>       SQLSVCPASSWORD:                
>       SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$WENDISQL2017
>       SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             
>       SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
>       SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
>       UIMODE:                        Normal
>       X86:                           false
>
> ```
> Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180123_165114\ConfigurationFile.ini
> ```
>
> Detailed results:
>       Feature:                       Database Engine Services
>       Status:                        Failed
>       Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
>       Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
>       Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
>       Component error code:          0x84B40002
>       Error description:             The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.
>       Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402
>
> ```
> Feature:                       SQL Browser
> Status:                        Passed
>
> Feature:                       SQL Writer
> Status:                        Passed
>
> Feature:                       Client Tools SDK
> Status:                        Passed
>
> Feature:                       Client Tools Connectivity
> Status:                        Passed
>
> Feature:                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility
> Status:                        Passed
>
> Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
> Status:                        Passed
>
> Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
> Status:                        Passed
>
> Feature:                       Setup Support Files
> Status:                        Passed
> ```
>
> Rules with failures:
>
> Global rules:
>
> There are no scenario-specific rules.
>
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180123_165114\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?